# Constrain output values within a specified range

Tags: python

In this simple nested for loop, how can I in an elegant fashion set a constraint forcing a value to always within the range >0<1? If the lower or upper limit should be violated, then default to specified max or min values.

```
for factor in [1.2, 1.3]:
    for i in [0.8, 0.1, 0.5]:
        print(i*factor)
```

```
Output:
0.96
0.12
0.6
1.04
0.13
0.65
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen if result is not within range?

Comment: Forced to max or min depending on which threshold it breaks, upper or lower.

Comment: Well, use `max()` and `min()`…?

Comment: `result = max(0, min(i*factor, 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to silently force the variable in between 0 and 1 you can use `min` and `max` together like

```
min(1, max(0, i * factor))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `min()` and `max()` functions to cap any value between 0 and 1:

```
for factor in [1.2, 1.3]:
    for i in [0.8, 0.1, 0.5]:
        print(max(0, min(1, (i*factor))))
```